# Нет данных через php://input

Tags: php, laravel, postman

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
print_r($data);
ничего не возвращает при отправке данных через postman
{
"group_id": 3917273,
"type": "wall_post_new",
}
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вернуть:  echo $data, а то и json_encode($data)

Comment: А вообще: что значит "ничего не возвращает"? откуда и куда?

Comment: вк отправляет данные о новом комментарии допустим, скрипт должен увидеть, что было отправлено

print_r($data);  пусто

Comment: ну судя по коду, ты передаёшь GET, а php:input берет данные из POST (если конкретно то из BODY)

Comment: пост данные передаю

Comment: Посомтри просто `file_get_contents('php://input')` ... Есть подозрение. что тебе надо просто брать данные из $_POST .....  включи отладочку посмотри внутренности и того и другого в дебаге

Comment: чтобы боди с json передавать надо вон на самом верху на картинке перейти на вкладку Body, а не на Params

Comment: teran спасибо все работает
надо в body выбрать raw и изменить на json

Answer (score 2):

По оформлению `null` мне показалось, что вы используете Laravel (для VK API с головой достаточно Laravel Lumen).
В нем есть специальный фасад для использования данных запроса:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class EventController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function newPost(Request $request)
    {
        $group = $request->json('group_id');  // 3917273
        $group = $request->input('group_id'); // 3917273
    }
}
```

Пожалуйста, изучите возможности Laravel в его [документации](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/requests), не нужно придумывать велосипеды для базовых вещей, которые присутствуют в нем из коробки.